# Update local storage of service worker, Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a custom Image Search extension with manifest v3. I need to save the config set by the user in the extension's options (search engine name, url etc), for that I am using [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/)  in my options.js

the problem is when I import the options.js script to the worker using [importSripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts), only the initial storage data (at the time of installing the extension) is imported, not the changes made by the user later.

so I tried importing the scripts every time the user does an image search but that gives an error that the scripts can only be imported at the time of installation.

I also tried using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead but that just gives an error, localStorage is not defined.

Comment: The question is unanswerable without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try not to import the script every time
but try to retrieve chrome.storage.local content every time you have to use some items held in it.
In this way you are sure to not lose any update made by the user.
This code can also be included in your service worker script, so when the service worker restarts after his natural rest you will be sure that the "lS" variable will contain the updated content of chrome.storage.local.

```
var lS;
(async () => {
    let np = new Promise((ok, ko) => {
        chrome.storage.local.get(null, lv => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError)
                ko(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            else
                ok(lv)
        })
    });
    lS = await np;
})();
```